# UIDocumentPickerViewController is not working when testing with my iPad but fine with simulators

Tags: swift, xcode, iso, pdfkit, ios14

I am creating an app to display a PDF file selected by `UIDocumentPickerViewController` for iPads.
Although the following code works fine with simulators of Xcode, for some reason, it won't work with my test iPad (iPad Mini, 5th gen). I can select a file, and its URL seems to be obtained appropriately; however, the PDF file is not displayed.

I would appreciate it if you could help me figure out what is happening and how to fix this.

```
import UIKit
import PDFKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate,  UIDocumentPickerDelegate {
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var pdfView: PDFView!
    
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        
        //document picker
        let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: ["com.adobe.pdf"], in: .import)
        documentPicker.delegate = self
        documentPicker.allowsMultipleSelection = false
        present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    internal func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAt url: URL) {
        print(url)
        if let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(url: url)
        {
            pdfView.autoScales = true
            pdfView.document = pdfDocument
            pdfView.displayDirection = .horizontal
            pdfView.usePageViewController(true, withViewOptions: [UIPageViewController.OptionsKey.interPageSpacing: 20])
        } else{
            print ("error, which is what I am seeing in my iPad now")
        }
    }
    
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
```

details of the environment:

- iPad mini: 5th gen, iOS 14
- Xcode: 14
- Simulators: iOS 14 (I tried the
  majority of simulators and the app works well with them all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are neglecting the fact that the `url` is *security scoped*. See the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller) in the section called "Working with External Documents".

(Also note that in iOS 14 your [initializer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller/1618678-initwithdocumenttypes) is deprecated. But that's another matter.)

Comment: Thank you for your insight, @matt! While reading the website you posted, I changed `url` -> `fileUrl` to eliminate the potential ambiguity in code where ` if let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(url: url)`. (and other places) And now the app is actually working. Do you have any thoughts on this? Thanks!

Comment: That makes no sense. You must have different code from what you've shown me.

Comment: You're right! I replaced back `fileUrl` with `url`, and the app is still working. Although I did not intentionally change anything else, I might have played with some other places and changed something.. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 2):

For me, in my case, it was a security issue. Adding this simple code resolved the issue:

```
let shouldStopAccessing = pickedFolderURL.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
        defer {
          if shouldStopAccessing {
            pickedFolderURL.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
          }
       }
```

I got this code from here: [StackOverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60498625/reading-files-from-external-storage-in-ios-13)